# add () around \ref{}

Tags: formatting, cross-referencing

How can I add `[` and `]` around `\ref{myref}` so that I get something like this:

```
[1.1]
```

This does not work:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,allcolors=blue]{hyperref}
\let\oldref\ref
\renewcommand{\ref}[1]{[\oldref{#1}]}
\begin{document}
\section{Section}
Why cannot include square brackets around cross references? \ref{S}
\subsection{Subsection\label{S}}
This is a subsection.
\end{document}
```

Ans: comment out `\usepackage[colorlinks=true,allcolors=blue]{hyperref}` and it works. But I need `hyperref`, I do not want to use `amsmath`, and I prefer not to add packages as they tend to clash with other things later on, such as using plastex, etc. What can I do?

Comment: Use `\eqref` from the `amsmath` package.

Comment: Better, ignore `\eqref` and put in your preamble `\usepackage{fncylab} \labelformat{equation}{(#1)}`, so that `\ref` applied to an equation's label is styled like `\eqref` and normally otherwise, *and* when `hyperref` is used, the link encompasses the parentheses.

Comment: Or use `cleveref`.

Comment: I don't trust anything that is self-described as "clever" :)

Comment: @RyanReich +1 :-)

Comment: @RyanReich I don't trust anything that is self-described as _fancy_. ;-)

Comment: @PaulGessler The choice of name is even more insidious: it's *fncy* [sic]. If the package had the courage of its convictions, if wouldn't have dropped the "a" `:p`. Just kidding, of course.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since `hyperref` redefines things after the `\begin{document}`, you could defer the `renewcommand` to be `\AfterBeginDocument` as:

[image]

### Notes:

- This won't work with the starred variant `\ref*`.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{letltxmacro}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,allcolors=blue]{hyperref}

\AtBeginDocument{%
    \LetLtxMacro\oldref{\ref}%
    \DeclareRobustCommand{\ref}[2][]{[\oldref#1{#2}]}%
}

\begin{document}
\section{Section}
Why cannot include square brackets around cross references? \ref{S}
\subsection{Subsection\label{S}}
This is a subsection.
\end{document}
```

Comment: The usual *caveat*: with `hyperref`, `\ref` is defined with `\DeclareRobustCommand`, so `\LetLtxMacro` should be used, not `\let`. Moreover you're breaking the possibility of `\ref` to be called as `\ref*` (which doesn't create a hyperlink).

Comment: quote: "you could defer the renewcommand to be \AfterBeginDocument:" How exactly? can you show how to do it in the MWE shown?

Comment: @egreg; Thanks. Have updated it to use `\LetLtxMacro`.

Comment: @Echeban: Perhap I misunderstood, but the MWE I posted _does_ show how to use `\AtBeginDocument`'.

Comment: yes, you are right. thank you. I was able to make it work by moving my original command right after \begin{document} as in     \begin{document} 
\let\oldref\ref \renewcommand{\ref}[1]{[\oldref{#1}]} % Is this OK to do or will it cause some trouble ?

Comment: Yeah that _will_ work. However, I would recommend trying to separate form from content. The content should go _after_ `\begin{document}` and the preamble should control the output.  Hence, I would recommend you put it in a common preamble and use`\AtBeginDocument{}`.

Answer (score 3):

I'm upgrading my comment to an answer, since it seems to be one.

Rather than using `\eqref`, put this in your preamble:

```
\usepackage{fncylab}
\labelformat{equation}{(#1)}
```

so that `\ref` applied to an equation's label is styled like `\eqref` and normally otherwise, and when `hyperref` is used, the link encompasses the parentheses.

Note that although you can use this technique for other kinds of label, there is a bug in `amsthm` so that, if you use `\newtheorem` in the form `\newtheorem{<new theorem>}[<old theorem>]{...}`, the `<new theorem>` will have *literally* the same counter as the `<old theorem>`, and `fncylab` (and indeed, `cleverref`) will label them identically.  The workaround is that, after defining the theorems, you must also duplicate their counters:

```
\usepackage{aliascnt}
\newaliascnt{<new theorem>}{<old theorem>}
\labelformat{<new theorem>}{...}
```

This will work as expected.  I do this with lots of counters in anything I write.