# Two different kind of reference in a document

Tags: cross-referencing, captions

I want to use two different kind of reference in a document: one is default with command `\refa{} “1.1”`, and another is added `()` around `\ref` with command `\ref{} “(1.1)”`. I use: [add () around \ref{}](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/176577/add-around-ref)
for kind 2.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{letltxmacro}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,allcolors=blue]{hyperref}

\AtBeginDocument{%
    \LetLtxMacro\oldref{\ref}%
    \DeclareRobustCommand{\ref}[2][]{[\oldref#1{#2}]}%
}

\begin{document}
\section{Section}
 brackets around cross references: \ref{S}‎\\‎
 default type with \refa{s} i.e 1.1
\subsection{Subsection\label{S}}
This is a subsection.
\end{document}
```

Comment: You cannot use numbers in macro definitions.

Comment: I am not quite sure in which siturations, the brackets should be used, i.e. which version.

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: two reference like this command and output: One) command: \refa{s} output: 1.1 , Two) command: \ref{s} output: (1.1)

Comment: Isn't `\refa` for parenthesized references and `\ref` for normal ones clearer?

Comment: @egreg is `\refa` an existing command?

Comment: @Alenanno Of course no; the OP is asking for one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you want something like this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{letltxmacro}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,allcolors=blue]{hyperref}

\AtBeginDocument{%
    \LetLtxMacro\refa{\ref}%
    \DeclareRobustCommand{\ref}[2][]{(\refa#1{#2})}%
}

\begin{document}
\section{Section}
 brackets around cross references: \ref{S}‎

 default type with \refa{S} i.e.~1.1
\subsection{Subsection\label{S}}
This is a subsection.
\end{document}
```

[image: fixed cross-references]

Answer (score 3):

Is next simple solution what you looking for:

- `\ref{...}` for referencing just a number
- `\pref{...}` for referencing look `(<number>)`, where is `refp` defined as:

  `\newcommand{\pref}[1]{(\ref{#1})}`

Example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,allcolors=blue]{hyperref}

\newcommand{\pref}[1]{(\ref{#1})}

\begin{document}
\section{Section}
 brackets around cross references: \pref{S}‎\\‎
 default type with \ref{S} i.e 1.1
\subsection{Subsection\label{S}}
This is a subsection.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is done automatically for equation references, `\ref{}` vs `\eqref{}`